# How to include libs without touching them, but incorporating sourcemaps

Tags: gruntjs

As an example, let's presume I have a file structure similar to this:

```
- libs
- controllers
- etc
```

I am uglifying and generating sourcemaps for all files inside `controllers` and `etc`.

Now I want to concatenate all files in libs to the newly uglified files and merge the sourcemaps (the files in libs already have sourcemaps and are minified).

I don't want to change any of the files in libs.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In this one case, I would use `concat` after everything is said and done on `uglify`'s side. That way the `lib` files would merge seamlessly into the already uglyfied files...

Comment: Yeah, but that wouldn't play nice with sourcemaps I believe.